# Handling hibernate Bidirectional relationships One to Many

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, foreign-keys

I have two tables inside of my legacy application.

`Host` and `Tables`. Table `Host` has a foreign key relationship `(Tables_fk) column` with `Tables`. In my code I have a method as below.

```
public class Tables {
    public void addHosts(Host host) {
         getHostsCollection().add(host);
    }
}
```

Now I am splitting my database and `Tables` will go into a separate database. I am now dropping the column `Tables_fk` from `Host` and adding a column `Table_ID` there which I will write from my application. Now since I am writing the `Table_ID` to the host table from the application, I am guessing there is no need for the `addHosts(Host host)` mwthod to exist as of now.

Am I right? Also what does Hibernate add with that method since the `Tables` table does not have any foreign key relationship with `Host`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you drop a table within your database, hibernate will no longer work for ManyToOne relationship (Table entity) so:

> you need to remove your ManyToOne annotation within your Table class
>   and then change it to **@Transient** or remove the **hosts** variable
>   entirely together with **getters and setters**

And if you do so, your relationship ***is not Bi-Directional anymore***, that relationship will become **Uni-Directional** and it works fine and you still can fetch all of your "tables" column rows!

> Take note adding column is different with adding a Foreign Key and the
>   section you have mentioned about dropping Tables_fk creates ambiguity